# How do I integrate Hook0 with my other applications?

Tags: hook0

I'm looking to integrate webhook support in my SaaS application in NodeJS. I'm interested in using the open-source webhook server Hook0 to programmatically let my end users create webhooks subscription inside my application and react to event.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hook0 can be integrated with other applications in a variety of ways. Here are a few examples:

- Using the **Hook0 API** ( https://documentation.hook0.com/reference ): The Hook0 REST API allows you to programmatically integrate Hook0 with your applications. This is the most flexible way to integrate Hook0, but it requires some coding knowledge.
- Using the **Hook0 Webhooks UI** ( https://app.hook0.com/ ): The Hook0 Webhooks UI allows you to create and manage webhooks without any coding knowledge. This is a good option if you want to integrate Hook0 with a simple application.

Here are the steps on how to integrate Hook0 with your other applications using the **Hook0 API**:

- Create a Hook0 account and generate an API key.
- In your application, make a request to the Hook0 API using your API key.
- In the request, specify the event type that you want to subscribe to.
- Hook0 will send a webhook to your application when the event occurs.

Here are the steps on how to integrate Hook0 with your other applications using the **Hook0 Webhooks UI**:

- Go to the Hook0 Webhooks UI.
- Click the "Create Webhook" button.
- In the "Event Type" field, select the event type that you want to subscribe to.
- In the "Webhook URL" field, enter the URL of the endpoint in your application that will receive the webhook.
- Click the "Create Webhook" button.

Hook0 will send a webhook to your application when the event occurs.